# CRM Configuration Migration - Currency

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I create a record in CRM that contains an option set and 4 currency fields, I export the record using the CRM Configuration Migration tool, I delete the record in CRM, and finally I import the record that I just exported.  After the import I was expecting to see a record identical to the one that I exported and deleted however the option set field is populated but none of the currency fields are populated - weird.  I open the zip file that was created by the export process, I open the data.xml file within it, and I locate one of the currency fields:

```
<field name="new_rate1" value="&amp;#163;‎1.00" />
<field name="new_rate1_base" value="&amp;#163;‎1.00" />
```

If I manually remove the '&#163;' from the first row, i.e.

```
<field name="new_rate1" value="‎1.00" />
<field name="new_rate1_base" value="&amp;#163;‎1.00" />
```

and import the data the currency field value will be imported correctly.  Surely I shouldn't have to manually edit the XML file.  I believe that this is either a bug in Configuration Migration tool or that I am doing something wrong, but I can't think what.  Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Did the currency type of those fields exist in the target system? Did you look at the log files? You should be able to find the log files under : `c:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataMigrationUtility\<Version>`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @Nicknow.  I found the following in the error log

DataMigrationUtility.Import Warning 4 Adding new_entityname to the reprocess List as field new_rate1 () - (action:Update) failed validation for reason code: None
DataMigrationUtility.Import Warning 4 Adding new_entityname to the reprocess List as field new_rate1_base () - (action:Update) failed validation for reason code: None

The currency type exists in the target, in this scenario the target is the same as the source system as I am trying to eliminate all other factors that could be causing the problem